# Como deletar colunas agregadas em um Dataframe Pandas obtido através do 'pivot_table'?

Tags: pandas

Olá, gerei um Dataframe no Pandas com o seguinte comando:

```
df_projects7 = pd.pivot_table(df_projects8, index=['id_prj', 'Nome do Projeto', 'criado_em'], values=['Percent_executado', 'Atualizado'], aggfunc=[np.min, np.mean])
```

Com o seguinte resultado: As colunas 'Id_prj', 'Nome do Projeto' e 'criado em' , ficaram como índices e foram agregadas colunas: amin com 'Percent_executado', amin com 'Atualizado' e mean com 'Percent_executado', mean com 'Atualizado'.

O comando df_projects7.dtypes retorna:

amin  Atualizado               int16
      Percent_executado        int64
mean  Atualizado             float64
      Percent_executado      float64
dtype: object

Preciso deletar as colunas: amin com 'Percent_executado' e mean com 'Atualizado'. Pois só fazem sentido no contexto as colunas: amin com 'Atualizado' e mean com 'Percent_executado'

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Olá, JcrRocha. Você consegue compartilhar com nós uma amostra dos dados para que ele seja reproduzível? pode ser algo bem pequeno com até 5 ou 10 linhas. Leia aqui como criar um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, no entanto acabei contornando o problema e achei uma solução que me atendeu. Eu fiz um pivot_table para o Percent_realizado com o 'amin' e outro pivot_table para o 'Atualizado' com a função 'mean' e depois efetuei um merge dos dois dataframes gerados. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você está atrás da função dataframe.drop().

```
df_projects7=df_projects7.drop(['Percent_executado','Atualizado'], axis=1)
```

Avise se funcionar.

Comment: Olá, agradeço por sua resposta, no entanto não funcionou (KeyError: 'Percent_executado'). Repare que não é um dataframe comum, pelo menos eu acho, pois foi obtido com o pivot_table que o transforma como se fosse uma tabela dinâmica do excel. Ele cria níveis hierárquicos : o 'amin' e o 'mean' e embaixo de cada um deles o 'Percent_executado' e o 'Atualizado', portanto eu tenho duas colunas com 'Percent_executado' e duas com 'Atualizado'. E quero eliminar a coluna 'Percent_executado' que está abaixo do 'amin' e a coluna 'Atualizado' que está abaixo do 'mean', as outras duas preciso manter. Blz.